# Adjusting info.plist at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I am writing a SDK that can be incorporated in a large variety of app configurations, especially pertaining to their `Info.plist` settings, most notably the various `UIBackgroundModes` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` settings.  I would like to write unit tests that verify my SDK's behavior under these settings. To be specific, I want to make sure my SDK's code correctly handles the OS-level behavior resulting from the Info.plist settings. I realize I can set up separate unit testing targets in my Xcode project, each having a distinct combination of settings. However, that would become a combinatoric nightmare. Is there anyway I can accomplish my goal pragmatically in my unit test code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't test reading directly from Info.plist. Instead:

- Build your tests around querying a dictionary
- Add a test confirming that you can correctly build a dictionary from Info.plist

Comment: This is not quite the right sense of my problem. I want to make sure that my code correctly handles the OS-level behavior resulting from the app's info.plist configuration.